# Excepciones error en java

Tags: java, excepciones

No me funciona la excepción que le puse a mi código. Ademas como podría hacer que me vuelva a solicitar ingresar el dato luego de reconocer el error,
algo así

```
catch(InputMismatchException ex){
                System.out.println("Debe ingresa obligatoriamente un nro");                
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debe ingresa obligatoriamente un nro",
      "ERROR!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
              String p=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Usted trabaja?"
                    + "Responda 1 si trabaja o 2 si no");
```

este seria el pedacito del código con problemas. Agradecería mucho su ayuda.

```
try {
            do{
            String p=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Usted trabaja?"
                    + "Responda 1 si trabaja o 2 si no");
              rta= Integer.parseInt(p);
            }while(rta!=1 && rta!=2);
            }catch(InputMismatchException ex){
                System.out.println("Debe ingresa obligatoriamente un nro");                
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debe ingresa obligatoriamente un nro",
      "ERROR!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La excepción `InputMismatchException` es lanzada por la clase Scanner cuando el elemento recibido no corresponde al tipo de dato esperado, al tu ingresar un texto no numerico se producira un `Numberformatexception` por que estas haciendo un cast para la variable `rta` es por eso que no salta el mensaje *"Debe ingresa obligatoriamente un nro"* ,para ello puedes usar solo `Exception`,ahora tu bucle debe aplicarse cuando se ingrese un dato diferente de 1 o 2 y ahora si es que se ingresa un texto no numerico que evite el cast.

Para ello haremos uso de una variable boolean

```
boolean pass=true;
```

esta vez el `try-catch` debe ir dentro del bucle `do-while`

```
do{
String p=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Usted trabaja?" +
" Responda 1 si trabaja o 2 si no");
try {
    //Si se ingresa 1 o 2 cambiamos el valor de pass a false para que no se repita el bucle   
rta= Integer.parseInt(p);
pass=false;
        
}catch(Exception ex){            
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debe ingresa obligatoriamente un nro","ERROR!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        
      }
   }
    //en caso caiga en la excepcion pass seguira siendo true por ende se repetira el bucle oen caso se ingrese un valor diferente de 1 - 2 
while (rta!=1 && rta!=2 || pass);
```